# Collapsing the Unit Ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

For a homework question, I need to prove that $\mathbb{R}^n/\overline{B_1(0)}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $\overline{B_1(0)}$ is the unit ball centered at the origin. Clearly, the inclusion map $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\overline{B_1(0)} \hookrightarrow \ \mathbb{R}^n/\overline{B_1(0)}$ is a homeomorphism onto an open set; can I use this fact somehow and smoothly extend this map to produce a homeomorphism between the total spaces?

Comment: Just write down an explicit map that is one to one and onto and show it is continuous and has continuous inverse. The map should send a "collar" of the boundary of the ball (i.e. an $S^1 \times [0,1)$) to a punctured neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: Consider $r \mapsto r - 1$

Comment: Thank you for your responses! The map $r \to ŗ - 1$ is what I thought of first, but I couldn't figure out how to show continuity and openness; the hint about the punctured neighbourhood of the origin helped me in the end.